# How to display item from an object in a random order and keep their respective property

Tags: javascript, html

What i am trying to achieve is to get 3 items out of X number in the history_case object.

I would like to have all property of those items display inside my html code at random.

Exemple : I would like to display the item (FISH), with the tile, url and image that refer to it.

An item cannot appear twice.

P.s. I am new to javascript

P.p.s English is not my first language

```js
var history_case = {
    "francais": [

        {
            "title": "CAT",
            "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat",
            "image": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0b/Cat_poster_1.jpg/260px-Cat_poster_1.jpg"
        },
        {
            "title": "DOG",
            "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dog",
            "image": " https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d9/Collage_of_Nine_Dogs.jpg/260px-Collage_of_Nine_Dogs.jpg"
        },
        {
            "title": "DUCK",
            "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck",
            "image": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/bf/Bucephala-albeola-010.jpg/220px-Bucephala-albeola-010.jpg"
        },
        {
            "title": "FISH",
            "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fish",
            "image": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/23/Georgia_Aquarium_-_Giant_Grouper_edit.jpg/220px-Georgia_Aquarium_-_Giant_Grouper_edit.jpg"
        },

    ]
};

randomTitles(); // this now calls a single function that will create the three titles and put them into the html

function randomTitles() {
    var arr = history_case.francais;
    var arrLength = arr.length;
    var titlesArray = [];

    // the following creates the array of unique titles - it will only push a title to the array if it isnt already in the array - preventing duplicates
    while (titlesArray.length < 3) {
        var randomItem = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arrLength)];
        var title = randomItem.title;
        if (titlesArray.indexOf(title) == -1) {
            titlesArray.push(title)
        }
    }
    // the following sets the titles from the titlesArray into the html.
    titlesArray.forEach(function (title, index) {
        document.querySelector('.history_title_' + (index + 1)).innerHTML = title;
    })

    ;
};

randomUrl(); // this now calls a single function that will create the three titles and put them into the html

function randomUrl() {
    var arr = history_case.francais;
    var arrLength = arr.length;
    var urlArray = [];

    while (urlArray.length < 3) {
        var randomItem = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arrLength)];
        var url = randomItem.url;
        if (urlArray.indexOf(url) == -1) {
            urlArray.push(url)
        }
    }

    urlArray.forEach(function (url, index) {
        document.querySelector('.history_url_' + (index + 1)).href = url;

    })

    ;
};


randomImage(); // this now calls a single function that will create the three titles and put them into the html

function randomImage() {
    var arr = history_case.francais;
    var arrLength = arr.length;
    var imageArray = [];

    // the following creates the array of unique titles - it will only push a title to the array if it isnt already in the array - preventing duplicates
    while (imageArray.length < 3) {
        var randomItem = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arrLength)];
        var image = randomItem.image;
        if (imageArray.indexOf(image) == -1) {
            imageArray.push(image)
        }
    }
    // the following sets the titles from the titlesArray into the html.
    imageArray.forEach(function (image, index) {

        document.querySelector('.history_image_' + (index + 1)).src = image;

    })

    ;
};
```

```css
.container{
  display:flex;
  width: 900px;
  text-align:center;
}

div{
  width: 33%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

img{width:200px;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>



<body>
    <div class="container">

        <div>
            <h2 class="history_title_1"></h2>
            <a class="history_url_1" href="">
                <img class="history_image_1" src="">
            </a>

        </div>
        <div>
            <h2 class="history_title_2"></h2>
            <a class="history_url_2" href="">
                <img class="history_image_2" src="">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h2 class="history_title_3"></h2>
            <a class="history_url_3" href="">
                <img class="history_image_3" src="">
            </a>

        </div>

    </div> <!-- end of container-->
    <script src="history_case_url.js"></script>
</body>



</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of the issue is that you are only calling the random selection once and so each time you use the value - you are using the same value.

By putting the random item generator into a function and calling that - you will get a different random item each time the function is called.

**EDIT - I have altered my answer to provide a mechanism to only have unique titles being passed into the html. Essentially - creating an array of three unique titles and then passing those titles to the html.**

You should probably put some smarts in there to remove an item if its already been selected - to prevent the random selection of the same item, but the following should give you a start.

```js
var history_case = {
    "francais": [

        {
            "title": "titre 1",
            "url": " https://unsplash.com/t/wallpapers",
            "image": "https://unsplash.com/photos/xW7Cdhoe9uA"
        },
        {
            "title": "titre 2",
            "url": "https://unsplash.com/t/architecture",
            "image": "https://unsplash.com/photos/MYQT7kTCBwI"
        },
        {
            "title": "titre 3",
            "url": "https://unsplash.com/t/business-work",
            "image": "https://unsplash.com/photos/8qEuawM_txg"
        },
        {
            "title": "titre 4",
            "url": "https://unsplash.com/t/food-drink",
            "image": "https://unsplash.com/photos/mO1LXRLeLFs"
        },


    ]
};

randomTitles(); // this now calls a single function that will create the three titles and put them into the html
 
 

function randomTitles(){
  var arr = history_case.francais;
  var arrLength = arr.length;
  var titlesArray = [];
  
  // the following creates the array of unique titles - it will only push a title to the array if it isnt already in the array - preventing duplicates
  while(titlesArray.length < 3) {
    var randomItem = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arrLength)];
    var title = randomItem.title;
   if(titlesArray.indexOf(title) == -1) { 
      titlesArray.push(title)
    }
  }
  // the following sets the titles from the titlesArray into the html.
  titlesArray.forEach(function(title,index) {
    document.querySelector('.history_title_' + (index+1)).innerHTML = title;
  })
  
  ;
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>



<body>
  <div class="container">
    
    <div >
      <h2 class="history_title_1"></h2>
      <a href=""></a>
      <img src="" >
    </div>
    <div >
        <h2 class="history_title_2"></h2>
      <a href=""></a>
      <img src="" >
    </div>
    <div>
      <h2 class="history_title_3"></h2>
       <a href=""></a>
      <img src="" >
    </div>
    
  </div> <!-- end of container-->
    <script src="history_case_url.js"></script>
</body>



</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a function to get the random title and call it three times.

```js
var history_case = {
    "francais": [

        {
            "title": "titre 1",
            "url": " https://unsplash.com/t/wallpapers",
            "image": "https://unsplash.com/photos/xW7Cdhoe9uA"
        },
        {
            "title": "titre 2",
            "url": "https://unsplash.com/t/architecture",
            "image": "https://unsplash.com/photos/MYQT7kTCBwI"
        },
        {
            "title": "titre 3",
            "url": "https://unsplash.com/t/business-work",
            "image": "https://unsplash.com/photos/8qEuawM_txg"
        },
        {
            "title": "titre 4",
            "url": "https://unsplash.com/t/food-drink",
            "image": "https://unsplash.com/photos/mO1LXRLeLFs"
        },


    ]
};

function getRandomTitle() {
  return history_case.francais[Math.floor(Math.random() * history_case.francais.length)].title;
}

var title1 = document.querySelector('.history_title_1');
var title2 = document.querySelector('.history_title_2');
var title3 = document.querySelector('.history_title_3');

title1.prepend(getRandomTitle());
title2.prepend(getRandomTitle());
title3.prepend(getRandomTitle());
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>



<body>
  <div class="container">
    
    <div >
      <h2 class="history_title_1"></h2>
      <a href=""></a>
      <img src="" >
    </div>
    <div >
        <h2 class="history_title_2"></h2>
      <a href=""></a>
      <img src="" >
    </div>
    <div>
      <h2 class="history_title_3"></h2>
       <a href=""></a>
      <img src="" >
    </div>
    
  </div> <!-- end of container-->
    <script src="history_case_url.js"></script>
</body>



</html>
```

Note that you could get repeated titles with this method.

Answer (score 0):

Change `random` into a function, which other answers have pointed out, but what they failed to do was to destroy duplicate choices. To do this we use a `Set` object which will not allow duplicates, and make random choices until we get three different return values. Then we simply store the returned values and use them to populate the page!

```
var random = () => history_case.francais[Math.floor(Math.random() * 
history_case.francais.length)],
randomChoices = () => {
let chosen = new Set();
while (chosen.size < 3) {
  chosen.add(random());
}
  return [...chosen];
}
```

```js
var history_case = {
  "francais": [

    {
      "title": "titre 1",
      "url": " https://unsplash.com/t/wallpapers",
      "image": "https://unsplash.com/photos/xW7Cdhoe9uA"
    },
    {
      "title": "titre 2",
      "url": "https://unsplash.com/t/architecture",
      "image": "https://unsplash.com/photos/MYQT7kTCBwI"
    },
    {
      "title": "titre 3",
      "url": "https://unsplash.com/t/business-work",
      "image": "https://unsplash.com/photos/8qEuawM_txg"
    },
    {
      "title": "titre 4",
      "url": "https://unsplash.com/t/food-drink",
      "image": "https://unsplash.com/photos/mO1LXRLeLFs"
    },


  ]
};



var random = () => history_case.francais[Math.floor(Math.random() * history_case.francais.length)],
  randomChoices = () => {
    let chosen = new Set();
    while (chosen.size < 3) {
      chosen.add(random());
    }
    return [...chosen];
  }
var random_array = randomChoices();
var title1 = document.querySelector('.history_title_1');
var title2 = document.querySelector('.history_title_2');
var title3 = document.querySelector('.history_title_3');

title1.prepend(random_array[0].title);
title2.prepend(random_array[1].title);
title3.prepend(random_array[2].title);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>



<body>
  <div class="container">

    <div>
      <h2 class="history_title_1"></h2>
      <a href=""></a>
      <img src="">
    </div>
    <div>
      <h2 class="history_title_2"></h2>
      <a href=""></a>
      <img src="">
    </div>
    <div>
      <h2 class="history_title_3"></h2>
      <a href=""></a>
      <img src="">
    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- end of container-->
  <script src="history_case_url.js"></script>
</body>



</html>
```